# How to set the OID from the NDIS FILTER DRIVER itself without using any application?

Tags: windows, device-driver

Hi Can anyone suggest me a way to do it safely.

I am working on NDIS Filter driver, I need to set the Desired OID from the filter driver itself without using the application.

In general application will send the IOCTL with the desired OID, But in this case I need to avoid the application to set the desired OID, i.e., I Need to trigger the OID from the Driver itself.

Any inputs will be of great help !!

Comment: Why not just send the ioctl from your filter driver yourself?  You'll want to obtain the name of the target device and roll an IRP_MJ_DEVICECONTROL IRP.